# Blocking a City or Region from website

Tags: .htaccess, ip

I know it is easy to block an individual IP address or a whole country from viewing my website via htaccess, however I need to block a city in the UK only and have the visitors from the blocked city redirected to another external URL.

Here is some code I already have for my htaccess file, but I have been searching everywhere on how to block just a UK city or region. Where would I find the range of IPs for a specific UK city? or is there a better way of doing this?

```
    # BAN USER BY IP
    <Limit GET POST>
     order allow,deny
     allow from all
     deny from (an individual IP address or range)
     </Limit>


     ErrorDocument 403 http://www.google.com
```

Comment: Have you looked into GeoIP?

Answer (score 4):

you have to use **IptoLocation** Script(http://www.ip2location.com/) and then you can check the city or region after that Blocking a City or Region from website.

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to do this. First you can use any geoIP API to query the location of the visitor. Just google geoIP API to see what's available. There are online solutions and downloadable databases as well.

You can also "wire in" the banned IP address blocks into your webapp. You can query block information at http://location2ipaddress.com/ for example. If you want to use the .htaccess file to do this, then all you need is the ip range data - put this into the deny list and you're done.

Whatever you do, blocking is a delicate topic.
It is easy to go around the block by using proxy servers.
Blocking whole ranges is risky, you are preventing innocent users from accessing your website. There is no harmless, 100% safe way to do this.